# Thermalization in black holes in terms of infalling information

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information, hawking-radiation

I was reading the "black holes as mirrors" paper by Hayden and Preskill which can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.4025)

Anyways, I had a more generic question. If I throw a quantum state into a large black hole, what does it mean to say there there is a finite time for the infalling information to get thermalized. Is this similar to adding a few drops of cold water into a glass of hot water and saying that there is a finite time for the temperature field in the glass to become uniform - basically to come to thermal equilibrium. If this is the case, does it mean that if after a split instant after the quantum  state has fallen in, if Hawking radiation happens to be emitted from exactly the same spot on the event horizon as the point where the quantum state had fallen in, there's a greater chance of it carrying information about the quantum state than if the Hawking radiation was emitted at a point diametrically opposite on the event horizon?